# In R: how to remove gaps in date-time series plot when using posixct for date-time column?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, posixct

This is a problem for which i cannot find any help online.

Here is the link to the original data (too large to paste here): 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5KaRU02aEnAbnM5ODNPMkYxN0E

and here is its structure

```
> str(dfsite)
'data.frame':   11712 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Site_ID      : chr  "02AB08-001" "02AB08-001" "02AB08-001" "02AB08-001" ...
 $ Deployment_ID: num  15352 15352 15352 15352 15352 ...
 $ RecDate      : chr  "01-07-2007" "01-07-2007" "01-07-2007" "01-07-2007" ...
 $ RecTime      : chr  "00:00:00" "00:30:00" "01:00:00" "01:30:00" ...
 $ Temperature  : num  19.5 19.5 19.6 19.6 19.6 ...
 $ TimeStep     : num  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 $ RecYr        : Factor w/ 19 levels "1996","1997",..: 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ RecDT        : POSIXct, format: "2007-07-01 00:00:00" "2007-07-01 00:30:00" "2007-07-01 01:00:00" "2007-07-01 01:30:00" ...
```

---

The RecDT column consists of daily data from 00:00:00 to 23:30:00 for the entire month of July for many years:
1) 2007-07-01 00:00:00-23:30:00 to 2007-07-30 00:00:00-23:30:00
2) 2009-07-01 00:00:00-23:30:00 to 2009-07-30 00:00:00-23:30:00
...

I would like to create a time series plot for each year which shows day 1 to day 30 of July for a specific site_id.

My current code creates a time series plot 
-for all the months but it should only have the month of July
-for all the years but it should create facets for different years

```
# original data
df <- excel file
# extract year only
df["RecYr"] <- substr(df$RecDate,7,10)
df$RecYr <- as.factor(df$RecYr)

#extract date and time
df["RecDT"] <- paste(df$RecDate,df$RecTime)
df$RecDT <- as.character(df$RecDT)
df$RecDT <- as.POSIXct(df$RecDT,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

# select specific site
dfsite <- df[df$Site_ID == "02AB08-001",]

# import ggplot2 and create plot
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dfsite, aes(x=dfsite$RecDT, y=dfsite$Temperature))  + 
  geom_point() +
print(p)
```

[here is my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v4H5.png)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Any chance you could share the data using `dput()`? It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. Also, welcome!

Comment: @EricFail please, see google drive link for dataset. thank you.

Comment: Any change you could make a smaller, i.e. _minimal_, data-set where the problem could be reproduced?

Comment: @EricFail  I'm sorry but it is difficult for me to reduce the data without changing the purpose of the question. I don't know how to manipulate different time scales, therefore i had to provide  the 30mins interval data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be:

```
x <- cumsum(table(dfsite$RecYr))
x <- cbind(c(1,x[-length(x)]),x)
xseq <- c(apply(x,1,function(kk) round(seq(kk[1],kk[2],length.out=3))))

p <- ggplot(dfsite, aes(x=1:nrow(dfsite), y=Temperature))  + 
  geom_point() + facet_grid(.~RecYr, scale="free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous("Time", breaks=xseq, 
        labels = dfsite$RecDT[xseq])+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))
print(p)
```

[image]